# How to get an exact match of the value using SendKeys with C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm having to click on a drop-down item in a list. The list has values like Approve, Reject, Send, Send For Dispatch

I'm using the following code which works for options such as 'Approve' and 'Reject', but when I try it for 'Send' it clicks 'Send For Dispatch'. Is there a way I can match it for exact text. Here is the code I use, in the code, the filterValue holds the status I want to click.

```
IWebElement setValue = Resources.Wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'drop')]")));
            new Actions(Resources.Driver)
                .MoveToElement(setValue)
                .SendKeys(setValue, Keys.Backspace)
                .SendKeys(setValue, filterValue)
                .SendKeys(setValue, Keys.Enter)
                .Build()
                .Perform();
```

Comment: We have no idea how your html looks like, so how should we give you an answer here. If it selects the wrong button then probably your XPATH is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It does select the correct drop-down, as mentioned it works fine for selecting drop-down item Approve but when selecting Send. It basically searches for 'Send by dispatch' - so dropdown is not matching exact words